# Unable to access an element of an array() PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I had 14 li elements with various information in and thought it's be better to wrap it all up into a php loop and use variables and arrays to fill in the gaps.

I've encountered two problems.  The first of which is that I'm not returning any elements from the array description or title.

The next problem is in the filename `$iFINAL.pdf` - it should just be the variable `$i` with FINAL appended to it.

I wouldn't normally use EOT but in this case it seemed far quicker than escaping all the various quotes.

any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
    <?php
$description = array("Decription 1 here","description 2 here");
$title = array("title 1","titlesfdfs ","sdfsdsd","wqeqe","","");

for($i=1; $i <= 14; $i++){

    if($i < 10){
        $i = "0".$i;
    }

$body = <<<EOT

<h3><a href="#">Chapter $i - $title[$i]</a></h3>
<div class=trainingItemListContainer>
    <div class="mainDetails">
        <p><strong>Introduction:</strong> $description[$i]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subDetails">
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="training_chap$i.php"><p>Click to view the chapter</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="../download.php?filename=/trainingHandoutPDF/$iFINAL.pdf">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click to download the PDF file&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../images/disk.png" alt="downloadIcon" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOT;

echo $body;
}
```

Comment: the output needs to be insider the loop

Comment: Wrap all variables in braces, i.e. `{$i}` and `{$title[$i}}`.

Comment: @BLaZuRE there's no reason to wrap normal variable identifiers like `$i` in `{}`. you only need to wrap those that include symbols like `[` or `->`

Comment: @BLaZuRE that worked brilliant for the $iFinal issue, still can't access the array though.

Comment: @sgroves In his code, s/he has `$iFINAL.pdf`.  How does PHP know if s/he wants `$i`, `$iFINAL`, or anything inbetween?  I think it's evaluating `$iFINAL` and outputting an empty string, as a guess.  Plus, it adds to the readability, which is always worth it in programming.

Comment: oh, well obviously in that case you need them

Comment: doh! miss counted the brackets. :(

Comment: @Dagon - i wish you were right though:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Several issues here:**

**(1) This code is causing problems:**

```
if($i < 10){
    $i = "0".$i;
}
```

**WHY?** if you did a `var_dump($i)` (= simple debugging), you'd realize that

`$title[1]` is different from `$title['01']`

**solution**: delete the above code.

**(2) an array in PHP will start with index 0, not 1.**

```
echo $description[1];
```

will output "description 2 here".

**solution**:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 14; $i++) {

   $number = str_pad(($i + 1), 2, "00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
   ...
   <h3><a href="#">Chapter $number - $title[$i]</a></h3>
```

see it working here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/489laJ

Comment: I wasn't over the moon about appending a leading 0 to i.  I don't know enough php to be aware of the other methods but I assume that is what STR_pad does?  Will chck out the manual but thanks!

Comment: @user2608855: Yes, this is what `str_pad` does. check out the other changes I proposed.

Answer (score 2):

There are two major issues with your code:

- You're setting the value of `$i` to `01`, `02` etc. This will cause the script to produce Undefined Index errors because there's no such index in your array.
- You're not enclosing the variables in `{ }`. If you enclose it, the actual variable values will be used. For example: `{$i}`

**Example:**

```
$body = <<<EOT

<h3><a href="#">Chapter {$i} - {$title[$i]}</a></h3>
<div class=trainingItemListContainer>
    <div class="mainDetails">
        <p><strong>Introduction:</strong> {$description[$i]}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subDetails">
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="training_chap$i.php"><p>Click to view the chapter</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="../download.php?filename=/trainingHandoutPDF/{$i}FINAL.pdf">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click to download the PDF file&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../images/disk.png" alt="downloadIcon" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
EOT;
```

Comment: @sgroves: in the OPs code, the script will just try to (I think) evaluate the value of `$iFINAL` (which is not defined) and will be empty. Wrapping the variables in `{ }` does fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem within your code, you are changing the value of `$i` (reassigning another value with it here):

```
if($i < 10){
    $i = "0".$i;
}
```

You can alternatively use another variable such as `$j`

```
 if($i < 10){
    $j = "0".$i;
 }else{
    $j = $i;
 }
```

This might not be your exact problem, but it might help you to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this?

```
<?php
$description = array("Decription 1 here","description 2 here");
$title = array("title 1","titlesfdfs ","sdfsdsd","wqeqe","","");

for($i=1; $i <= 14; $i++){

    if($i < 10){
        $i = "0".$i;
    }

?>

<h3><a href="#">Chapter <?php print($i." - ".$title[$i]); ?></a></h3>
<div class=trainingItemListContainer>
    <div class="mainDetails">
        <p><strong>Introduction:</strong> <?php print($description[$i]); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="subDetails">
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="training_chap<?php print($i); ?>.php"><p>Click to view the chapter</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="viewAndDownload">
            <a href="../download.php?filename=/trainingHandoutPDF/<?php print($i);?>FINAL.pdf">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click to download the PDF file&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../images/disk.png" alt="downloadIcon" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you have PHP code later on, just open the `<?` tag again!

Comment: Tried it : I get an error of  syntax error, unexpected $end with no closing brace and when I add the closign brace at the end <?php} ?> I get an error saying it's unexpected but when removed the loop is never closed